# htaccess css is not recognize and broken link

Tags: .htaccess

I've a problem with my .htaccess, my css is not recognize, and all links are broken . . .
I have two domain register on the same hosting,

(eg number 1 and number 2)

I've manage to make number two working perfectly with this .htacess, which is located in: /number2domain/

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews


<Files ~ "^.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^css/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^js/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [PT]
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"
</FilesMatch>


RewriteRule ^(\w+)/rss?$ rss.php?lang=$1

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/product/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=product&category=$2&subcategory=$3&product=$4&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/product/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=product&category=$2&subcategory=$3&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/product/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=product&category=$2&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/project/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?toptype=project&type=$2&lang=$1&ext=$3
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/project/(\w+)?$ index.php?toptype=project&type=$2&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/page-(\w+)?$ index.php?type=$2&page=$3&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?toptype=$2&type=$3&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=$2&lang=$1


#ErrorDocument 400 ./error/400.html
#ErrorDocument 404 ./error/404.html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php      
order deny,allow
```

However, I don't manage to make work number1, which is located in /httpdocs/home/

I've keep the .htacess rewritting the

```
RewriteBase /
```

by

```
RewriteBase /httpdocs/home/
```

but it doesnt change anything . . .

In my config file, which is:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_CONFIG_INC_PHP'))
{
    define('_CONFIG_INC_PHP', 1);
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost'){
        $_CONFIG['MysqlHostname'] = 'hostname';   // host name
        $_CONFIG['MysqlUsername'] = 'user';        // username access to mysql
        $_CONFIG['MysqlPassword'] = 'pass';      // password access to mysql
        $_CONFIG['MysqlDatabase'] = 'dbname';
        $_CONFIG['Website_host'] = 'http://domain1.com./';
        $_CONFIG['Website_folder'] = '/httpdocs/home/';

    }else{
        $_CONFIG['MysqlHostname'] = 'hostname';   // host name
        $_CONFIG['MysqlUsername'] = 'user';        // username access to mysql
        $_CONFIG['MysqlPassword'] = 'pass';      // password access to mysql
        $_CONFIG['MysqlDatabase'] = 'dbname';
        $_CONFIG['Website_host'] = 'http://domain1.com./';
        $_CONFIG['Website_folder'] = '/httpdocs/home/';
    }
    $_CONFIG['MysqlCharset'] = 'UTF8';
    $_CONFIG['PageCharset'] = 'UTF-8';
    $_CONFIG['TablePrefix'] = 'lam_';
    $_CONFIG['SitePrefix'] = 'CMS_';
    $_CONFIG['ImageResize'] = '1';
    $_CONFIG['UploadRename'] = '0';
    $_CONFIG['ThumbnailsWidth'] = '140';
    $_CONFIG['SEOFile'] = 'seo.xml';
    $_CONFIG['WEBSITE'] = 'domain1.com.gt';
    $_CONFIG['DefaultLanguage'] = '1';
    $_CONFIG['Email'] = 'mail';
    $_CONFIG['Trace'] = false;
}
```

I've change the path, or keep the previous one (

```
$_CONFIG['Website_folder'] = '/';
```

}

Any highlite will be wonderfull . . .

Thank you so much

Comment: What is correct path of CSS and how are you including it in your page?

Comment: the path is at: httpdocs/home/style/

it's in the index.php as:

<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: So working css path should be `http://example.com//home/css/style/style.css` ?

Comment: It doesnt change anything, it;s a matter with the htacess setup,But i cano manage which one :s, in the ej i gived about, number2 i susing exactly the same files and framework, it's just the path and some content which differ both of them...

Comment: You're mistaken. I didn't give you solution but asking questions to understand what is your **full working URL for CSS files**

Comment: ow, sorry, misunderstood :)

the url is: http://lamett.com.gt/style/style.css

Comment: ok can your include your css as: `<link href="/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: hm, it looks better, but the links are still all broken : do you have a skype by any chance ?

Comment: Sorry no skype at work. You have to make sure to use same absolute paths for all js, css and image files.

Comment: hmm . . how come for the domain2 which is in the same hosting at /domain2/

thehtacess file solve everything, I can not rewrite all path in each file, its using a framework, it should be an easier solution via the htacess no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relative URLs are broken, either add a `/` to all of your links, images, styles, scripts, etc, or add this to your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

(or possibly)

```
<base href="http://lamett.com.gt/" />
```

Comment: Noen of thos works . ..  I ve add iton top of my header file  .. :(